# podspec specification does not validate

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to create a cocoa pod following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/99386/create-cocoapod-swift). I'm stuck at the moment where I'm doing the following command:

> pod repo push RWPodSpecs RWPickFlavor.podspec

the problem is that I've got the following error:

```
Validating spec
[!] The `RWPickFlavor.podspec` specification does not validate.
```

And not further error description unfortunately. What I tried was reinstalling cocoapods and installing cocoapods keys, but it didn't help. I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, the problem was very simple actually. I was simply being unobservant. In my `.podspec` file I had one of the urls formatted like that : `["https://github.com/Andrey-C/RWPickFlavor.git"]`. Once I removed the square brackets around the url the error vanished.

Answer (score 27):

I solved this issue by adding option `--allow-warnings`.

Answer (score 9):

While the OP's issue was fixed, using this command will give more information about anyone else's issue. For me, I forgot to push the new version tag to my remote.

```
pod repo push [repo] [podspec] --verbose
```

Comment: @Aleksandr, you can change the chosen accepted answer if you'd like :)

Comment: really? How to do that?

Comment: I believe you can click on the check mark on the existing chosen answer to remove it, then select the new one.

Comment: Oh, sure u can do that, if u're an owner of a question. I can't :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `pod spec lint` doesn't update changes (this is because of cache).

Once I fixed some errors specified by lint, pushed, updated `tag`, etc., and ... got the same errors as before.

So you can fix it by cleaning cache:

```
cd /Users/<#your-user-directory#>/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods
```

just delete **/Pods** directory and `pod spec lint` will work again

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to add a revision tag to my master branch and then git push with all tags before the pod trunk push would pass validation.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command:

```
pod trunk push RWPickFlavor.podspec
```

It publishes your newly created pod to CocoaPods repository, creating a pod with name that specified in your `.podspec` file.

You also have to use such command to publish a new version of your pod.